# createConnection MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node.js app that uses MongoDB as a database.
I have also the management of MongoDB.
When the app starts, it connects to MongoDB without any problem.
I am trying to let the user defines which database he/she will connect to. To do that I create mongo.conf like that:

[image]

And in the app, I defined the connection uri like that:
**MONGODB_URL="mongodb://< username>:< password>@34.72.5.46:27017/"**

The database user has the **root** role. As I mentioned, in first opening the app connects to the database. In the first opening, I am using **mongoose.connect**
But when the user inserts a database name that doesn't exist, via the app, I am using mongoose.createConnection. And then I get this error:

**MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [34.72.5.46:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.**

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe share the code you are using to connect? Most likely the `username:password` are incorrect.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek username and password are correct. As I mentioned, I can connect at the first opening of the app. But then I am using createConnection method of mongoose library. The code is like that:

```await mongoose
      .createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_URL.concat(req.body.company))```

Comment: What does the mongod log say about the authentication attempt?

Comment: @Joe well I can't retrieve logs back but I solved my issue. It has been needed to add "?authSource=admin" at the end of the mongo URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue. It has been needed to add "?authSource=admin" at the end of the mongo URI